# Can anyone help how to get total number of variables and clauses generated by Z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to know how many variables and clauses are actually generated when a z3py file runs

Comment: Can anyone explain this?
(:max-memory 6.48
:memory 6.48
:mk-bool-var 1
:num-allocs 1102926
:total-time 0.05)
This is what I get when I run "z3 filename.smt -smt2 -st"

Comment: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions is a better forum for these kinds of questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.